# Can I use Google mobile ads without publish my android application

Tags: android, admob

My question is very simple, can I use `Google AdMob` ads in the android app without publishing it in google play? because when I try to use the real banner ads in my app am getting this message `LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config)`.

be aware I have added my mobile device as a test device and the ads was working fine, but when removed my device from the mobile test devices list in my `Google AdMob`. am getting the mentioned error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Advertisement works in two ways.

While The App Is In Development.

While The App Is In Production.

Scenario 1: While the App Is In Development

For this case, we need to use Test Advertisements. Admob and "com.google.android.gms.ads" doesn't allow the user to use Advertisements in Development Phase due to false impressions.

To enable Test Advertisement. There are two ways: You can either use google ad unit id's which are available on their site. Or You can use your own ad unit id, but you will be needing to register your device as a test device and use your own request configuration.

Go to AdMob page and settings>test devices and add your device as a test device directly from the site no need to do this programmatically!
and boom! you get the test ads from your ad unit and you can safely use your app!

Scenario 2: While the App Is In Production

This is a pretty simple part...

Just remove the .setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("your device id should go here")) part from the code... (If you had set programmatically)
Link your AdMob App to PlayStore.
Just opt for the ad.
And check if Ads are enabled in your app settings on the play console.
It should work now.

YOU CAN'T USE ADMOB ADS WITHOUT HAVING PUBLISHED YOUR APP IN THE PLAY STORE OR OTHER VERIFIED STORES (CHECK THEIR BLOG TO KNOW THE OTHER STORES YOU CAN UPLOAD) IF YOU DO NOT PUBLISH IT MAY RESULT IN A VIOLATION OF ADMOB POLICY AND YOU MAY BE SUSPENDED! SO, BE CAREFUL.

Comment: thank you very match brother that was loud and clear answer .this is exactly what I want to know.  
thanx

Comment: Glad to know that , if this helps please mark this answer. So other users may know this is the exact solution

Comment: You can use Unity ads without publishing your app in any store.